# Replace Adjacent Elements of Circular Array to Make All Elements Equal

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

You are given a circular array A containing N integers. You can perform the
following operation on this array any number of items:

• For each i, replace A[i] by A[i-1], A[i] or A[i+1] i.e. you can keep the
current element or replace it by an adjacent element . Note that due to
circularity of the array adjacent elements exist even for the first and
the last element. In particular, A[i-1] for i=0 is the last element.

Determine the minimum number of steps needed to make all the elements of
the array equal.

Input Format
The first line contains an integer, N, denoting the number of elements in A.
Each line i of the N subsequent lines (where 0 $i< N) contains an integer
describing A[i].
Constraints
1 <= N <= 10^3

Sample input: 4 2 2 1 1 => Sample output: 1

Sample input:3 1 1 1 => Sample output: 0

Sample input:4 1 2 3 4 => Sample output: 2

I build the following code, it passes all visible test cases on platform, but not passing invisible test cases(that i'm not sure, what are they).Please help me to find any edge cases, if i forgot something here.

```
from collections import Counter
def make_equal(A):
    count = 0
    idx = []
    map = Counter(A)
    value = sorted(map.values(), reverse=True)[0]
    for k, v in map.items():
        if v == value:
            key = k
    for i, val in enumerate(A):
        if val == key:
            idx.append(i)
    new_set = set(idx)
    while len(new_set) < len(A):
        for j in idx[:]:
            l = (j + 1) % len(A)
            m = (j - 1) % len(A)
            idx.append(m)
            idx.append(j)
            idx.append(l)
        count += 1
        new_set = set(idx)
    return count

print(make_equal(A))
```

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages

Comment: Why are you tagging this problem with `c++`, and `java`?

Comment: because logic can be provided in any language, its a problem solving question, there was no tag for problem-solving so tagged language